Recoding NAs as a different level in a factor
I have data collected on pregnant women. Some data pertains to women's previous pregnancies (e.g. asking if they have had a previous large baby). For women who are in their first pregnancies, the responses to those types of questions have been coded as NA. However, they are not missing data - they just cannot be answered. So when I come to run a multivariable model such as:
m <- glm(hypertension ~ obese + age + alcohol + maternal_history_big_baby + 
              premature, data = df, family = binomial())

I have just discovered that it will do a complete case analysis and all women with a first pregnancy will be excluded from the analysis because they have NA in maternal_history_big_baby. This means the model only reflects women with more than one pregnancy, which limits its generalisability.
Options:
i. what are the implications of changing the NAs in these types of covariates to a different level in the factor (e.g. 3)? I understand the output for that level of the factor will be meaningless, but will the logits for the other levels of the factor (and indeed the other covariates) lose accuracy?
ii. is it preferable to carry out two different analyses: one on women who are experiencing their first pregnancy, and one on women with more than one pregnancy?
I have tried na.action = na.pass but that does not work on my models.

Your question is essentially statistical, which is fine. It's important in principle and in practice to flag that you are using particular statistical software and to separate out details specific to your software.

Hurdle models have been devised for just this sort of situation.

It appears that maternal_history_big_baby is a binary variable with a yes/no answer. You are correct that coding women experiencing their first pregnancies as NAs isn't a good idea. You could instead treat it as categorical/nominal variable and simply define an additional category such as "no previous baby" (I'm setting aside the issue of miscarriages - how to address this would be a question for medical experts). The estimated coefficient for this category will not be meaningless - it should reflect the association between hypertension and a first pregnancy (though there are of course important assumptions involved).
You can also fit separate models to data from women undergoing their first pregnancy and the rest. This is likely to be less efficient, however.
There's a third option that I think is more useful in the case of continuous predictors. Imagine a predictor such as  mean_weight_of_previous_babies. You can define a separate binary yes/no predictor such as previously_had_baby. For women who are having their first pregnancy (so previously_had_baby = 'no'), you would then enter a zero for mean_weight_of_previous_babies. You would then include both terms in the model, but crucially, mean_weight_of_previous_babies would only be included as in an interaction term with the other predictor. So the model would look like:
hypertension ~ previously_had_baby + previously_had_baby:mean_weight_of_previous_babies

More about this last approach here: How do you deal with "nested" variables in a regression model?

Thanks for your response. I think I am leaning towards fitting different models for primiparous vs multiparous women as I tried changing the binary to a nominal categorical variable but then some crazy things happen with multicollinearity (and clinically I understand why this happens but I won't go into here) which seems to inflate my logits and standard errors. I don't have the birthweights of previous babies unfortunately.

Running two separate analyses would prevent you from evaluating the effect of maternal_history_big_baby across the entire sample.
Adding "false" NAs of maternal_history_big_baby as a new factor
level 3 sounds valid to me. It would effectively represent women that never had a baby before. You could relevel it as the reference level so the coefficients reflect contrasts to first time mothers. This will capture the effect structurally since the variances for all three categories are being considered in estimation and is probably what you want.
Another option you could try is estimating a risk model as a first stage and use the predictions as alternative to maternal_history_big_baby in the second stage—the actual analysis. Consult the literature on which biopsychococial factors predict having a big baby and use it as predictors of maternal_history_big_baby (there may be many, also consider meaningful interactions and possible polynomial terms, e.g. $age^2$). Usually risk is estimated using a logit model, but since your analysis model is also a logit model, the approach would suffer from bias due to non-collapsibility of logit models. To keep things simple you could use a linear probability model (LPM; i.e. using lm instead of glm) for the risk instead (with all its shortcomings). The $\hat Y$ (fitted values) of this model will reflect the risk of having such a baby—aka propensity scores. Include them alternatively in the the analysis model.
hypertension ~ obese + age + alcohol + big_baby_RISK + premature

Note that the risk model must be strong and carefully specified, otherwise biases may occur. You should probably bootstrap the standard errors of this second stage. The difference to the first approach is that this now uses the risk for variance estimation and no longer estimates distinct groups.
Finally, compare the two model results and try to interpret where differences might come from if they occur (including misspecification).

The solution to this scenario is that you want a model predicting an "average" response for those in their first pregnancy, and a "regression" model for those not in their first pregnancy.
The pragmatic solution here is to code the data as
     FIRST = 1 if NA (first pregnancy) and = 0 otherwise
and then recode
      big_baby = previous baby weight and zero if first pregnancy.
Then you will run the model as
      y ~ FIRST + FIRST : big_baby 
(note, there is not "main effect" for big_baby).
This will then result in two models for each group:

for first pregnancy, the model reduces to $y = b_0 + b_1 · \text{FIRST}$
for non-first pregnancies, the model reduces to $y = b_0 + b_2 · \text{big_baby}$

I've extracted just the key portion of your model, but the idea extends to more complicated regressions (as you have here).  As long as there is (nearly) complete data for the other variables, this should address your concern.

The output for using NA as a level will not be meaningless. Based on the question it clearly means it is their first pregnancy.
See below for code that adds NA as a level to a factor variable. If for some reason you need to access the values that are NA after this, it isn't exactly straight forward as is.na(x) returns FALSE for all observations after after adding NA as a level. See my answer in this question for a solution to that https://stackoverflow.com/a/78054642/17483781.
create a factor variable with two levels and missing values
set.seed(1)
x <- factor(sample(c(0,1,NA), size = 10, replace = T))

x
#[1] 0    <NA> 0    1    0    <NA> <NA> 1    1    <NA>
#Levels: 0 1

# add NA as a level
x <- addNA(x)
x
#[1] 0    <NA> 0    1    0    <NA> <NA> 1    1    <NA>
#Levels: 0 1 <NA>

